Using Mathematica to solve Newton's equations
I'm trying Mathematica to solve Newton's Equations describing the motion of  two masses gravitationally attracted to each other. I'm having trouble finding the equation for the interpolating function that I get as a result of NDSolve. Below is the Code that I'm using:
eps = 0.0001;

mypars = {m1 -> 10, m2 -> 10, bigG -> 1};

eqn1 = m1 D[x1[t], {t, 2}] - (
    bigG m1 m2)/( Abs[x1[t] - x2[t]] + eps)^3 (x2[t] - x1[t]);

eqn2 = m2 D[x2[t], {t, 2}] + (
    bigG m1 m2)/( Abs[x1[t] - x2[t]] + eps)^3 (x2[t] - x1[t]);

nsol1  = 
NDSolve[ {(eqn1 /. mypars) == 0, (eqn2 /. mypars) == 0, 
   x1[0] - 10 == 0, x2[0] - (-10) == 0, x1'[0] == 0, 
   x2'[0] == 0}, {x1, x2}, {t, 0, 100}]

Plot[{x1[u] /. nsol1, x2[u] /. nsol1}, {u, 0, 100}]

x1Function = x1 /. nsol1[[1]]
x2Function = x2 /. nsol1[[1]]

dataX1 = Table[{t, x1Function[t]}, {t, 0, 100, 0.1}];
dataX2 = Table[{t, x2Function[t]}, {t, 0, 100, 0.1}];

tapp1 = ResourceFunction["TrigApproximateList"][dataX1, t][[1]];
tapp2 = ResourceFunction["TrigApproximateList"][dataX2, t][[1]];

Plot[{tapp1, x1[t] /. nsol1}, {t, 0, 100}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 100}}, AspectRatio -> Full]
Plot[{tapp2, x2[t] /. nsol1}, {t, 0, 100}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 100}}, AspectRatio -> Full]


As you can see, the formulae that I used to fit the graph (tapp1,tapp2) are not good fits for both the equations for x1 and x2. Any ideas for which other functions I could use?

What exactly is your purpose of finding a fit? What do you want to do with it? It's important to know this when deciding what kind of a "fitting" procedure should be chosen ...

{x1[u] /. nsol1, x2[u] /. nsol1} are interpolation functions of the NDSolve solution. What do you expect from tapp1,tapp2?

my purpose is to solve the differential equations (Newtonian Law of Gravity) for x1 and x2 and get two sets of equations. Mathematica gives me interpolating functions for x1 and x2 but if I want to insert the equations for x1 and x2 into some other formula it'd be hard to do it without knowing the mathematical form of the equation.

The mathematical form of the interpolating functions are probably not meaningful in the physical sense.

What is this other formula? Generally, there will be no problem inserting the solution of NDSolve(which is an interpolating function) into some other formula and plot the graph.

If I understand your question and comment right try NDSolveValue :
eps = 0.0001;

mypars = {m1 -> 10, m2 -> 10, bigG -> 1};

eqn1 = m1 D[
     x1[t], {t, 
      2}] - (bigG m1 m2)/(Abs[x1[t] - x2[t]] + eps)^3 (x2[t] - x1[t]);

eqn2 = m2 D[
     x2[t], {t, 
      2}] + (bigG m1 m2)/(Abs[x1[t] - x2[t]] + eps)^3 (x2[t] - x1[t]);

{X1,X2} = NDSolveValue[{(eqn1 /. mypars) == 0, (eqn2 /. mypars) == 0, 
   x1[0] - 10 == 0, x2[0] - (-10) == 0, x1'[0] == 0, 
   x2'[0] == 0}, {x1, x2}, {t, 0, 100}]

The functions you're looking for are X1[t], X2[t]
Plot[Evaluate[{X1[t],X2[t]}],{t,0,100}]



I don't really see how this result is different from what the OP already has (namely x1Function and x2Function).

@Domen NDSolveValue gives the interpolation functions in one step, not more. No need to fit this result in a second step.
